# Getting the HttpRequest.responsexml null

Tags: javascript, httprequest

As I am trying to get the response of rest API, but it returns null.
Here is my JS code:

```
function submitApproval()
{
    //alert('Approval Start');
    var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //alert('Get Url');
    var url ='http://localhost:port/rest/bpm/wle/v1/task/303?parts=all';
    send_with_ajax(url);
}
function send_with_ajax(url){
    //  alert('Send Start'+url);
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //alert("Start");
    httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Alt-Referer", "http://www.google.com");
    alert("Send");
    httpRequest.send();
    alert('Send Request');
    var _tempRecommendations = httpRequest.responseXML;
    // window.alert(httpRequest.response)
    //window.alert(httpRequest.responseText)
    window.alert(_tempRecommendations);
    /*    
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        alert('onLoad call');
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            var _tempRecommendations = httpRequest.responseXML;
            window.alert(httpRequest.response)
            window.alert(httpRequest.responseText)
            window.alert(_tempRecommendations)
        }
    };*/  
}
```

How can I do this? I have tried onload and onreadystatechange but same result.

Comment: `send()` *after* setting the `onreadystatechange` handler.

Comment: In that code you NEED to use the onreadystate and you should check to make sure the response status is valid [aka 200]. Normal cause of null with responseText is invalid XML.

Comment: I have tried my url direct on browser and it return the status 200-OK,but after using onreadystate i got the undefined responsetext.

Answer (score 1):

You should send the request *after* setting the onreadystate handler to ensure that the handler is set before the response is received.

```
// set this first
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    window.alert(httpRequest.responseText);
};

// and then
httpRequest.send();
```

Comment: Through this i am getting responseText undefined.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/PRjYn/). check for `readystate` in `onreadstatechange` event

```
 function test(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

test();
```